# How do i retains a buttons clicked states once clicked and once the page reloads?

Tags: javascript, button, cookies, state, click

Im trying to figure out how to retain a buttons clicked state once cliked and after the page reloads.  In my code blow I use a onclick event so if I need to add another I'm capable of doing so... Just trying to figure out how to keep the clicked state.  Appreciate any time helping, Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#sub3 {
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
top: 200px;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
width: 180px;
padding: 10px;
color: black;
border: #0000cc 2px dashed;
display: none;
}
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">
function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
}
</script>

</head>
<body >

<input id="input1" type=button value='Show Layer' onclick="setVisibility('sub3', 'inline');";>

<div id="sub3">Message Box</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just pass something on url when clicked...dear

Answer (score 0):

have a javascript function for setting a cookie
Use these snippets for setting and getting the cookie values

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

Both functions are from [w3schools tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Because JavaScript is client side, every time you refresh the page you will lose information such as a click event by a user.

Assuming there is a specific reason that you need to refresh the page and can't use Ajax, you could accomplish what you want by setting a cookie on click, and then checking to see if that cookie was clicked on the next page load.

[This is a good primer for setting/retrieving cookies in JavaScript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).  There's also a good [Jquery plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for if you prefer that.

Essentially, in your `onclick` call you would call a function that sets a cookie with a value and also performs your setVisiblity function.

```
function clicked(id, visibility) {
    setVisibility(id, visibility);
    setCookie() // this calls your set cookie function
    return true;
}
```

On page load you would then have a function that checks to see if the cookie you just set exists.  If it does, then you can call your setVisibility function again to change style of the button.